# Automating facebook/twitter posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

We have a facebook app which does the job of posting updates throughout the
day fired after certain time gaps. These messages are posted to the fan page
and the same is posted on the twitter via twitter for facebook app. The
problem is it doesn't automatically post the messages as it should and throws
this error.

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError: OAuthException: (#100) The status you are
trying to publish is a duplicate of, or too similar to, one that we
recently posted to Twitter
```

The messages being:

```
"#Hashtag summary: N events have occurred in the past X hours. Stay tuned
for further updates."

"#Hashtag update: N events have transpired over the last X hours. Stay
with us for more updates."
```

Neither of them are being posted via command prompt.

However when I try to post is manually via fan page it doesn't complain and
messages are posted at both the locations.

Any help in this regard would be great.

Comment: Which API call are you using to make the updates?

Comment: Its facebook's page graph API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that twitter has been blocking the similar messages in the short time span. However this behavior shouldn't stop posting on facebook(but it gets aborted). Got around this by disabling auto-post on twitter and we're now posting at both locations separately.